# How do I change whatever object is in the center of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the following code which will dim any image that is not in the center of the window, but it only runs once. I am using onload to make sure I have the images, before manipulating them. I would like to change the opacity to 1 of any image in the middle of the screen.

```
     $(window).on("load", function scrolldim() {

        var xHome = window.innerWidth/2;
        var yHome = window.innerHeight/2;
        var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome).id;

                $( ".mid img" ).not( document.getElementById("#" + pElement ) )
 .fadeTo( "slow", 0.3 );

if($( ".mid img" ).attr('id') == pElement) {
    $("#" + pElement).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
}
```

Then I tried wrapping the call in a when statement, like below, but that didn't work at all.

```
 $.when(ajaxLoad()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){

                var xHome = window.innerWidth/2;
        var yHome = window.innerHeight/2;
        var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome).id;

                $( ".mid img" ).not( document.getElementById("#" + pElement ) )
 .fadeTo( "slow", 0.3 );

if($( ".mid img" ).attr('id') == pElement) {
    $("#" + pElement).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs only once, because there is no **EventListener**.(besides onload)

You basically say: "**When the document is loaded set the opacity of the images**". And that is what jQuery does(only once).

The thing is I don't know WHEN you want this function to be executed.

- When a button is clicked?
- When new image is loaded?
- Every couple of
  seconds?

***I will give you a simple example:***

- You want your function to be executed every 500ms(0.5s)

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    setInterval(scrolldim, 500); //call the scrolldim function every 0.5sec
});

function scrolldim(){
    
        var xHome = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var yHome = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome).id;
        console.log("500");
        $(".mid img").not(document.getElementById("#" + pElement))
        .fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
        if ($(".mid img").attr('id') === pElement) {
            $("#" + pElement).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should rerun when the page is scrolled.  There are little hover arrows. coolaidhouse.com/projectcaptured has the example